# Prove or disprove that for every vector $x=\binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}}$ and for every norm $\left \| * \right \|$ this is true.

Tags: normed-spaces

Prove or disprove that for every vector $x=\binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}}$ and for every norm $\left \| * \right  \|$ on the space $\mathbb{R}^{2} $

a)  $\left \| \binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}} \right \|=\left \| \binom{x_{2}}{x_{1}} \right \|$

b)  $\left \| \binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}} \right \|=\left \| \binom{-x_{1}}{x_{2}} \right \|$.

I see that it works for the standard Euclid's norm. But I guess there should be some norm, there this is not true. May be I should raise  $\left \| * \right  \|$ to a power 2 and work with an inner product to show it?

Comment: This looks suspiciously much like the one you posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

About a - you need to choose a non-symmetric norm, for example:

$ \left|\left|\left( \matrix {x_1\\ x_2} \right )\right|\right| =  \sqrt{2x_1^2 +x_2^2} $